# Getting image null vuejs symfony

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I'm trying to upload image to server from vuejs but on serverside I cannot to grab the image. I get `null` everytime. This is the vuejs code:

```
    submitFile() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file);
        fetch('/upload-image', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

And this is the symfony:

```
/**
 * @Route("/upload-image", methods={"POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function uploadImage(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->files->get('file');
    return new JsonResponse(['data' => $data]);
}
```

Returned data is `null`

Comment: Can you add
`.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});`
in the fetch and what return the console log

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear where does `this.file` come from. You can get file input just easy way.

```
const selectedFile = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
formData.append(selectedFile);
```

For more information please have a look [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).